# How to extend an object inside an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, function, client, anonymous-function, inheritance

I want to add another function called myFunction() into the CoreTeamObject, which is declared as local inside the anonymous function. Is this possible?

```
!function ($) {
    var CoreTeamObject = function () {
        var coreTeamVar1;   // ...
        this.someState = false;   // ...
        coreTeamFunction: function () { /* ... */ }
    };
}(window.jQuery);
```

Normally, I'd use prototype with something like:

```
CoreTeamObject.prototype.myFunction = function(){ 
  return 
};
```

But I simply don't know how to access the object.

Comment: Do you mean from outside the anonymous function? If so then you can't access `CoreTeamObject` directly, unless it's exposed somehow.

Comment: Yes, from the outside. Thank you.

Comment: How are you currently using the object? For the minimal code shown `CoreTeamObject` isn't accessible outside the anonymous function at all, so surely adding additional methods to it is secondary to making it accessible in the first place? Also your existing code has a syntax error, in that you have a label `coreTeamFunction:` followed by a function statement that doesn't have a name.

Comment: Specifically, it's a daterangepicker. The usage is just need to call .daterangepicker(...) on some jQuery selector. Just a regular jQuery plugin - it iterates over the given elements, and creates Objects with new.  https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker/blob/master/daterangepicker.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply can't. Variables within a function are **private** and cannot be accessed from the outside.

```
! function () {
    var foo = 1;
}();
// Calling `foo` will throw a referenceError here.

// It doesn't even work with classes...
var foo = function () {
    var bar = 2;
};
var bax = new foo();
// `bax.bar` doesn't exist.
```

However, there are workarounds. You could store them in a global variable (bad idea, though):

```
! function (w) {
    w.foo = 3;
}(window);
// window.foo = 3
// foo = 3
```

Or if you can rewrite it to a class:

```
var foo = function () {
    this.bar = 4;
};
var bax = new foo();
// bax.bar = 4
```

I hope this helps.